# Is there a way to recover bookmarks after Chrome Sync deletes them?

Tags: google-chrome

I set up chrome sync between two computers and someone decided to wipe out one of the folders in my bookmarks. Is there a way to get it back?

Answer (score 4):

According to this [Google Help forum post](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=4076890dee5f0183&hl=en):

> For Windows XP, go to: `C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local
>   Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`.
>
> For Vista, go to: `C:\Users\Administrator\Local Settings\Application
>   Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`.
>
> You can see a file named `Bookmarks.bak`. Maybe you can make a backup
>   copy of this folder for safety purposes, but it works out usually.
>   Delete the file `Bookmarks` and rename the file `Bookmarks.bak` to
>   `Bookmarks`.

Comment: I've edited your post and quoted where a quote was due. Please remember to add a proper quote if you copy/paste content from somewhere else. Thank you!

Comment: Note that Chrome creates a backup file every session, so you have to restore the backup file *right away* as soon as you detect the problem. I made the mistake of closing and re-opening Chrome once before trying to restore the backup. By that point, it had already been replaced with a copy of the new, corrupted bookmarks file.

Comment: I have done that but I still can't see the old bookmarks.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally to the other answers, in Ubuntu/Mint you can find the bookmarks in:

```
.config/google-chrome/Default/Bookmarks.bak
```